# round() returns different values

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I have a field in mysql DB `rating` with data type `float(2,1)`. One row contains a value `0.5`, but when I use

`SELECT round(rating) FROM table WHERE ...` gives value 0 instead of 1.

But `SELECT round(0.5)` gives value `1` (for Postgresql too).

Also, PHP always gives value `1` for `echo round(0.5);`

I am really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your data type from float(2,1) to decimal(2,1) it may works for you.

Comment: Interesting and also weird behavior. Good to know nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT ROUND(rating)` instead of `SELECT ROUND('rating')`.

ROUNDing a string might give you weird results. You're probably after the column value, which is not supposed to be escaped with `'`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo error in posting the question. But don't solve my question

Comment: Then this behavior doesn't make any sence. Are you sure you're rounding the correct row? Try `SELECT round(rating) AS rounded_rating , rating FROM table WHERE ...` and print us the result.

Comment: 0 and 0.5 respectively in two column.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
SELECT round('rating') FROM table WHERE ...
```

you are rounding the string 'rating' , that's why it gives you zero

try this one

```
SELECT round(rating) FROM table WHERE ...
```

Comment: yes that typo error is remove from the question. But it doesn't solve.